# Select an element with same class 2 times

Tags: html, css

I am working on a WordPress website and my menu is appearing as,

```
<li  class="current-menu-parent current-menu-item "><a  href="#">SHOP</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li class="menu-item-517 current-menu-item"><a href="#">Engine1</a></li>
        <li class="current-menu-item menu-item-516 current-menu-item"><a href="#">Engine2</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item-517 current-menu-item"><a href="#">Engine3</a></li>    
    </ul>
</li>
```

`Engine2` is my currently active page. the class `current-menu-item` is repeating 2 times in my active sub menu li.
How can I select my currently active submenu li using css?

I have tried with

```
.current-menu-item.current-menu-item{
}
```

but not working.

Please help me.....

[here](http://dev.brentuningmoto.com/) is the link to my website. Please visit the drop-down menu under shop.

Comment: There's no difference between having `<div class="a">` and `<div class="a a a">`. Both are the same. If you have to differentiate between the above two, it can't be done.

Comment: What `.current-menu-item.current-menu-item` does is that it increments its specificity.

Comment: @Ricky Got it, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I select my currently active submenu li using css?

Given your specific example; the element with the repeated class, has `current-menu-item` first, whereas the others do not. That being the case you can use "attribute begins with" operator: `[attr^=value]`. [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)

```css
[class^=current-menu-item]{
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<li  class="current-menu-parent current-menu-item "><a  href="#">SHOP</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li class="menu-item-517 current-menu-item"><a href="#">Engine1</a></li>
        <li class="current-menu-item menu-item-516 current-menu-item"><a href="#">Engine2</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item-517 current-menu-item"><a href="#">Engine3</a></li>    
    </ul>
</li>
```

This is very specific and prone to breaking if changes are made to your menu. The real fix would be to fix up the classes in your menu items.

Comment: The problem here, will it select the spaces as well? What if the starting of class doesn't have it?

Comment: What spaces do you mean? I did say it was very specific. It would work if every thing is juuust right

Comment: Never mind the spaces. What if the first class in the list is not that class?

Comment: Not a robust solution in any way. I commented on that in the answer.

Comment: Yea, gotcha. Thanks.

Comment: You may delete this answer, as this is a dupe... `:)`